# How to make a resizable div the is cross browser compatible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Here](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/)

is an example with jquery UI , [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp) is an example done with css3. The problem is the css3 will not work with any version of ie and I am looking to use an older version of jQuery UI -1.7.2 which I can't find. I'm using thhe older version because of the aging browsers we still support: IE 8,9 (recently dropped 7 finally).

I'm wondering if there are any other solutions available.

not sure what is not working

```
<html>
<head>
<title>resize</title>
<style>

#resizable { height: 250px; margin: 1em auto; width: 250px; }
h3 { text-align: center; }
</style>


    <script src="code/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="code/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="code/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="code/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="code/demos.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="code/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#resizable").resizable();
//alert("HODOR");
 });

</script>



</head>
<body>
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
     <h3 class="ui-widget-header">This is a resizeable window</h3>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [jQuery 1.7.2](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js) -- you don't need to go older than that to support IE8 in all facets. Although, if you insist: [1.6.4](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js)

Comment: FYI [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/J5FTD/show/) Works in IE 7,8, and 9. Just tested. Go to http://jsfiddle.net/J5FTD/ to see the code, short and sweet.

Comment: @ SpYk3HH did this work without installing any pluggins?

Comment: you can see in the jsFiddle. no plugins. just jQuery and jQueryUI, nothing more. I included the jQueryUI CSS, but that's it. no plugins

Comment: working straight from jsfiddle works great -I had some trouble with using the jquery ui when I downloaded it. I used the latest jquery-ui-1.10.3 and it worked but not in ie at all for some reason.